# Is there a leaner way to write this logic?

Tags: php

So I have the following logic to return a value if it's in the array or just return the original value if it's not:

```
$trnTitle = $translateMap[$title];
if($trnTitle)
   return $trnTitle;
return $title;
```

Is there a more sleek way to write this? I just feel like there's gotta be like one line I could write instead of calling the variable three times.

Comment: `$trnTitle = $translateMap[$title] ?? $title;`

Comment: `return $translateMap[$title] ?? $title` should work for php7+

Comment: For PHP it would be `??`

Comment: Overly "sleek" and/or "clever" code is usually both less readable and less maintainable. Don't try to shave down your source for no good reason.

Comment: Having an if statement without curly braces is asking for trouble :)

Comment: @Sammitch I agree but in this example it is perfectly ok

Comment: @Sammitch *code is usually both less readable and less maintainable* is overly cautious - it *can* be worse, but using the appropriate functionality is always better.  Especially as *$trnTitle = $translateMap[$title];* may be generating messages about undefined indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Since `php` 7 you can use the Null-Coalescing operator, if `$translateMap[$title]` is null, when not filled.

```
return $translateMap[$title] ?? $title;
```

See more information here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce

Comment: @AbraCadaver - I would have expected that is a deliberate choice - if there is a translation for the title to 0 or '', then it is there for a reason.  It may be that some things may be omitted in the result.

Comment: @NigelRen The original code is checking for a loose `true`, so NOT `null`, `false`, `0`, `''` empty array etc.  The null coalesce fails there and returns if it NOT `null` only.

Comment: @AbraCadaver do you think OP has tested it with 0 and '', so although you are correct you have to (IMHO) try and understand what they are trying to do rather than just follow their code blindly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from your code example what you are trying to achieve for 100%. I see two ways how to look at it.

1. You do not know if index `$title` exists in array `$translateMap`. If it exists you return its value from array or return the index itself:

`return $translateMap[$title] ?? $title;` <== http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

2. You know that index title exists in array translateMap and you are just checking if it's truthy. If it is truthy you return value from array otherwise index itself.

`return $translateMap[$title] ?: $title;` <== http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php#102060

Warning: This would fail if index `$title` does not exist in array `$translateMap`

---

Solution 2 is exactly what you have in your example

Answer (score -2):

You can use the null coalescing operator, which looks like `??`.

According to the [official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op),

> The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.

So just use this:

```
return $translateMap[$title] ?? $title
```

Credit to Nigel Ren's, Vody's, and Manual Otto's comments.

Comment: you forgot dns_nx's answer as credit. Also read the correct comment on that.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, it wasn't visible when I wrote my answer. Also, the original question isn't asking whether the returned value equates to false, so there's no need to check for that.

Comment: @Tim "the original question isn't asking whether the returned value equates to false" That's _exactly_ what `if($trnTitle)` does

Comment: `if($trnTitle)` is checking for value loosely equating to `true`.

Comment: @PatrickQ While we do want to check for the _existence_ of `$translateMap[$title]`, we do not care what it's value is. That comment asked what would happen if `$translateMap[$title]` equates to false. Answer: it doesn't matter. As long as `$translateMap[$title]` _exists_, the statement will return whatever is to the left of the `??`.